# Functional Tests with Intern.js: getVisibleText() does not work on dijits

Tags: dojo, intern

We are using dojo 1.13 with intern v3.
In one of our functional tests we are doing the following:

```
 .findByClassName('functionalTestWidget')
                .click()
                .sleep(1000)
                // check placeholder
                .getVisibleText()
                      .then(function (text) {
                          assert.strictEqual(text, 'Type here');  // SUCCESS
                      })
                .pressKeys('01/10/2010') 

                // press tab to get out of the control 
                .pressKeys('\uE004')
                .sleep(1000)                
                .end()

            .findByClassName('functionalTestWidget')
                .click()
                .sleep(1000)
                .getVisibleText()
                      .then(function (text) {
                          assert.strictEqual(text, '01/10/2010'); // FAILS : text is ''
                      })
```

although it can read the placeholder, after typing someting, pressing tab and then reselecting the widget, the getVisibleText returns an empty string

Comment: What type of dijit are you working with?

Comment: For this particular example was DateTimeTextBox, but it is the same behavior with ValidationTextBox, FilteringSelect, etc.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver's `getVisibleText` isn't intended to get the text content of an input element, which is is at the core of the text input Dijits. It works for placeholders because Dijit doesn't use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute on inputs, it actually adds a `span` with the placeholder text to the widget.

To get the text of an `input` you'll need to call `getProperty('value')` on the `input` element itself.